# How to manually generate calldata

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, delegatecall, calldata

Here's my code snippet:

```
function getCalldata(string calldata _func, string calldata _param1, uint256 _param2) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodeWithSignature(_func, _param1, _param2);
    }
```

I'm trying to write a function to manually generate the `calldata` by passing a function name and its parameters. Which keyword should be used in `getCalldata()` above: `calldata` or `memory`. I want to confirm if the snippet above is correct and the right keyword is being used (since the data being returned is `memory`).

For context, I have a contract with a delegatecall function and it requires passing calldata. (Also, please share any alternative ways to this).

```
function delegatecallContract(address _addr, bytes calldata _calldata) external payable returns (bytes memory) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) =  _addr.delegatecall(_calldata);
        require(success);
        return data;
    }
```